# Is there a term for when one claims that something can't be true of the collective because it is not true of every individual within the collective?

Tags: fallacies, terminology, definitions, categorization

Basically as the title says, I'm wondering if there is a term for when someone says that because there are some exceptions to the norm, that the norm cannot be considered as part or all of what defines something, that only traits that apply universally and without exception can be used in the definition of a group. So for example, a term that would apply if someone said, "we can't include the fact that cats grow fur within our definition of 'cat' because some cats are hairless," or "we can't say that humans have ten fingers because some humans have extra or missing fingers."

Comment: One can name it "refutation by a counter example".

Comment: I'm not referring to cases where someone is refuting the claim "all X are Y without exception," I'm referring to cases where someone provides "counterexamples" that do not sufficiently demonstrate that the general use definition of a term, meant to be broadly applicable in the vast majority of circumstances, is improper. For example if a person says, "refrigerators keep food cold," and another responds, "well, an unplugged refrigerator doesn't keep food cold, therefore 'keeps things cold' is not a defining characteristic of refrigerators."

Comment: Second attempt: "No true Scotsman fallacy".

Comment: For beings, the word is 'Borg'.

Comment: It sounds like the contrapositive to the [fallacy of division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fallacy_of_division), "when one reasons that something that is true for a whole must also be true of all or some of its parts." However, that usually refers to holistic properties of collections that do not distribute over their elements rather than to generic statements that distribute with implied exceptions. For that see comments on default logic and prototypical properties in [Relationship between basic statements of knowledge and rare exceptions](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/99092/9148).